# Relative Layout not Clickable

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

below is my xml :

```
     <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">
     <RelativeLayout
            android:clickable="true"
            android:id="@+id/rel1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">

            <com.app.thelist.view.CustomButton
                android:clickable="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:id="@+id/btn1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:text="btn1"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/txt_sub_title"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txt_barselection_size"
                app:FontEnum="regular" />

            <com.app.thelist.view.CustomTextView
                android:clickable="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:id="@+id/txt1"
                style="@style/RegularFont"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn_my_drinks"
                android:background="@drawable/border_gry_theme"
                android:padding="@dimen/dimen_3"
                android:text="00"
                android:textColor="@color/txt_sub_title"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txt_single_view_font" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_bootm_selecter2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="7dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/btn1"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
            android:clickable="true"
            android:id="@+id/rel1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">

            <com.app.thelist.view.CustomButton
                android:clickable="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:id="@+id/btn1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:text="btn1"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/txt_sub_title"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txt_barselection_size"
                app:FontEnum="regular" />

            <com.app.thelist.view.CustomTextView
                android:clickable="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:id="@+id/txt1"
                style="@style/RegularFont"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn_my_drinks"
                android:background="@drawable/border_gry_theme"
                android:padding="@dimen/dimen_3"
                android:text="00"
                android:textColor="@color/txt_sub_title"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txt_single_view_font" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_bootm_selecter2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="7dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/btn1"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

I have done findViewby id and added click listener to relative layout.. but it not taking click event.. instead click event is generating while i am clicking on textview inside relative layout.

What might be the isssue ?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want both textview and parent relative layout clickable or only relative layout?

Comment: Can you show your java code?

Comment: Now, after adding clickable and focusable false to my inner controls inside relativelayout, .. i have to click twise instead of single click on relative layout.

Comment: @ZaptechDevKumar I have added my answer below. Try with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The click event is passed from Child to parent. If any child is clickable then first child get the click event and if the child is not clickable then the click event pass to the parent.

If the parent wants click event before child then it needs to override `onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev);` in parent view class.

But if don't want to go with this then a simple solution is made child non-clickable. Please find the edited XML code in your case.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:clickable="true"
        android:id="@+id/rel1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

        <com.app.thelist.view.CustomButton
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:text="btn1"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/txt_sub_title"
            android:textSize="@dimen/txt_barselection_size"
            app:FontEnum="regular" />

        <com.app.thelist.view.CustomTextView
            android:id="@+id/txt1"
            style="@style/RegularFont"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn_my_drinks"
            android:background="@drawable/border_gry_theme"
            android:padding="@dimen/dimen_3"
            android:text="00"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:textColor="@color/txt_sub_title"
            android:textSize="@dimen/txt_single_view_font" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_bootm_selecter2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="7dp"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:layout_below="@id/btn1"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: so, you have done.. clikable and focusable = "false" to chiild ? Its the better solution ?

Comment: If you don't want to make child clickable then yes?

Comment: Sir, i am sorry but, my relative layout is under linearlayout

Comment: doesn't matter anything can be parent of relativelayout as told you click event is pass from child to parent and in such case relativelayout is child and LinearLayout is parent but you have to handle click event on RelativeLayout so it will work for you.

Comment: As no other child in Relativelayout is clickable which make pass click event directly to relative layout.

Comment: didn't get you? what do you mean by click twice?